# HTML option tags not loading after form submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an html page that loads list of hotels in a `select` tag from a MySQL table using PHP. The `select` tag is inside a `form` tag. Whenever I load the page, the `option` tags will load, but when I submit my `form`, the `option` tags never load anymore. My `form`'s `action` attribute is empty, I am checking everything on the same page, but when I put another php page as `action`, it loads normally. Is there a way to make it load after submit while keeping my `form`'s `action` empty?

Here is my code

```
<?php

require_once 'db.php';

$db = DB::get_instance();

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $hotel = $_POST['hotel_list'];

    $db->query("SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE Name='$hotel'");
    $hotel = $db->result()->current();

    $hid = $hotel['Hid'];

    $db->query("SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE Hid='$hid'");
    $rooms = $db->result();

    $db->disconnect();
}

?>

<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Display a hotel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" id="dsphtl">
            Name: <select name="hotel_list" form="dsphtl">
<?php
            $db->query("SELECT Name FROM hotels ORDER BY Name");
            foreach($db->result() as $row) {
                $t = $row['Name'];
                echo "<option value='$t'>$t</option>";
            }
?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" name="search">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$_POST['search']` is set, you `$db->disconnect();` so it can't run the query in your form.

Take the `$db->disconnect();` out of your `if()` statement, and put it at the end of the file.

Comment: I thought that submit would reload the whole page, which is why I put the `get_instance` method before the if statement to ensure there is a db object, and the `disconnect` at the end of the if because it would execute last.
It seems I understood wrong, anyway it worked, thanks TunaMaxx

Comment: No, the code is going to run top to bottom unless you tell it not to. So on a page load where $_POST['search'] is set, it's going to run through that if() statement, and then keep going right through into the HTML and generate the form.

Comment: Ohh, okay so its disconnecting from the database before reaching the form tag.
I understand it now, I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the disconnect, when the page reload after submit your connection to mysql lost due to

```
$db->disconnect();

<?php

    require_once 'db.php';

    $db = DB::get_instance();

    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $hotel = $_POST['hotel_list'];

        $db->query("SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE Name='$hotel'");
        $hotel = $db->result()->current();

        $hid = $hotel['Hid'];

        $db->query("SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE Hid='$hid'");
        $rooms = $db->result();
    }

    ?>

    <!doctype html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Display a hotel</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="" method="post" id="dsphtl">
                Name: <select name="hotel_list" form="dsphtl">
    <?php
                $db->query("SELECT Name FROM hotels ORDER BY Name");
                foreach($db->result() as $row) {
                    $t = $row['Name'];
                    echo "<option value='$t'>$t</option>";
                }
    ?>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" name="search">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```